# Verificando Hora em java

Tags: java, android

Dado uma lista com horários ex.: String[] horarios = {"11:00", "12:00", "13:00"};

Quero pegar minha hora atual e comparar com a lista qual é a próxima hora, ex.: hora atual é 11:30, pego da lista "12:00".

Comment: só de exemplo de como vou receber a hora(vou receber em string mesmo).

Comment: Essa `Time` é o que? `java.sql.Time`?

Comment: estou passando a string e faço o parse para Time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar datas você deve usar Calendar do Android.

```
Calendar horaComparar = Calendar.getInstance();
horaComparar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm").parse(horarios[0]));

Date horaAtual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

if (horaComparar.getTime().compareTo(horaAtual) > 0 ){
   // hora é posterior a hora Atual.
}
```

> - O valor de retorno é 0 se ambas as datas são iguais.
> - O valor de retorno é maior que 0, se data for posterior à data de argumento.
> - O valor de retorno é menor que 0, se data for anterior à data argumento.

Answer (score 3):

Se você estiver se referindo a classe [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html), então basta usar o método [`valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

```
String hora1 = "23:00";
Time n1 = Time.valueOf(hora1 + ":00");

String hora2 = "02:15";
Time n2 = Time.valueOf(hora2 + ":00");

if (n1.after(n2))...
```

Se você estiver usando a [`android.text.format.Time`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html), então veja o javadoc:

> **This class was deprecated in API level 22.**
>   Use [`GregorianCalendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) instead.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> **Esta classe foi depreciada na API nível 22.**
>   Use [`GregorianCalendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) ao invés disso.

Comment: Bem não sei direito qual o melhor pra usar mas o valueOf não resolveria, pois 23:00 continua dizendo que é depois de 02:15.

Comment: @Josinaldo, mas 23:00 é depois de 02:15! São 20 horas e 45 minutos depois.

Comment: entendo, então isso não ira funcionar para o que eu quero.