# Comparação de hora

Tags: java, android, time

por favor, estou tentando comparar horas (tipo Aberto Agora / Fechado Agora). Mas não estou conseguindo.
Para salvar a hora atual, estou usando:

```
   object.put("h11", h11.getText().toString());

                                object.put("h22", h22.getText().toString());
```

Mas está salvado como String;
Para pegar a hora atual estou fazendo assim:

```
 SimpleDateFormat hora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");

        Date data = new Date();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.setTime(data);
        Date data_atual = cal.getTime();

        String hora_atual = hora.format(data_atual);
```

Não está dando certo.
Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão de como comparar horário?
Obrigada

Comment: [Verificando Hora em java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74100/28595)

Comment: Oi Diego. Obrigada. Viu, esta "h:mm" , eu vou buscar no banco. Salvo como string?

Comment: Poderia mostrar qual o formato do **h11.getText().toString()** e **h22.getText().toString()** ? Obrigado!

Comment: Oi Thiago, eu usei um spinner para que o usuario escolha a hora,  mas já tem o timerpicker. Mas como achei que ia ficar muito grande, eu usei um spinner. h1 é o spinner das horas e min1 é o spinner dos minutos.

Comment: Thiago, para pegar a hora usei assim:
      h12.setText(hora1.getSelectedItem().toString()+":"+min1.getSelectedItem().toString());

Answer (score 3):

Você pode comparar horários utilizando os métodos `after` e `before` de [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Elaborei um pequeno exemplo em "puro Java" para ilustrar-lhe como fazer tal comparação:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainFrame {

    public final static SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    public final static String closeTime = "19:00";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What time is it? ");
        String presentTime = reader.next();
        boolean answer = checkIfClosed(presentTime);
        String textRepresentation = null;
        if (answer == true) {
            textRepresentation = "Nope! We're closed!";
        } else {
            textRepresentation = "It's open!";
        }
        System.out.println(textRepresentation);
        reader.close();
    }

    public static boolean checkIfClosed(String time) {
        try {
            Date present = parser.parse(time);
            Date closed = parser.parse(closeTime);
            if (present.after(closed)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Invalid date was entered
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Um campo define o horário de fechamento (`closeTime`), e um método (`checkIfClosed`) checa se no horário passado via input do teclado o hipotético estabelecimento está "aberto" ou "fechado", utilizando o método [after](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) de [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Answer (score 0):

fiz um metodo aqui, a maioria só funcionava quando não tinha horários de madrugada

esse compara até se esta de madrugada para manter aberto também...

agradeco :)

```
    public static boolean isIntervalOfHours(String horaAbre , String horaFecha) {
    String horaAtual = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date().getTime());// Pega hora atual do Sistema

    Integer horarioFecha[] = getHorAndMinute(horaFecha);
    Integer horarioAbre[]  = getHorAndMinute(horaAbre);

    if( horarioFecha[0] < horarioAbre[0] ) {
        Integer horarioAtual[] = getHorAndMinute(horaAtual);

        if(horarioAtual[0] <= horarioFecha[0]) {
            if(horarioAtual[1] >= horarioFecha[1] && horarioAtual[0] >= horarioFecha[0] ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }  else {
            horaFecha = "23:59";
        }
    } 

    try {
        if (isComparaHora(horaAtual, horaFecha) && !isComparaHora(horaAtual, horaAbre)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Horário Inválido...");
        return false;
    }

}
    public static Integer[] getHorAndMinute(String hora) {
    int horario, minutos;

    horario = Integer.parseInt(hora.substring(0, 2));
    minutos = Integer.parseInt(hora.substring(3, 5));

    return new Integer[]{horario, minutos};
}
private static boolean isComparaHora(String horaAtual, String horaFecha) throws ParseException {
    boolean fechaCaixa = false;
    if (!new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(horaFecha).before(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(horaAtual))) {
        fechaCaixa = true;
    }
    return fechaCaixa;
}
```